# install node packages using yarn warns remove package-lock.json even though no such file exists

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Install node packages using yarn warns remove package-lock.json even though no such file exists:
The project lists:

```
total 872
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root   4096 Dec 11 16:36 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 work work     36 Dec 11 16:36 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    245 Dec 11 16:36 .editorconfig*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1717 Dec 11 16:36 .env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     37 Dec 11 16:36 .eslintrc*
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root    198 Dec 11 16:41 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    442 Dec 11 16:36 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2068 Dec 11 16:36 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     70 Dec 11 16:36 .prettierignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    175 Dec 11 16:36 .prettierrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    774 Dec 11 16:36 .umirc.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     27 Dec 11 16:36 .vscode/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     23 Dec 11 16:36 .yarnrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1162 Dec 11 16:36 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     62 Dec 11 16:36 backend/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     45 Dec 11 16:36 baguazhen/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     22 Dec 11 16:36 mock/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2497 Dec 11 16:36 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1340 Dec 11 16:36 parse_brand.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     25 Dec 11 16:36 public/
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root    138 Dec 11 16:36 src/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 266177 Dec 11 16:37 test.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    513 Dec 11 16:36 tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    280 Dec 11 16:36 typings.d.ts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    468 Dec 11 16:36 webpack.config.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 558107 Dec 11 16:36 yarn.lock
```

And the `yarn` command shows:

```
work@apollo:~/buildspace/test$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.21
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
⡀ is-buffer@^1.1.5^C
```